# changed default attribute code to other and issues in shipping module

Tags: magento-1.9

I have changed the default attribute code(assigned other attribute in place of original) like

```
Attribute | Original | Assigned New
----------x----------x------------------
Height => | height =>|  dimension_height
Width  => | width  =>|  dimension_width
Length => | length =>|  dimension_length
Width  => | width  =>|  dimension_width
```

Now obviously this will not calculate the shipping cost. I'm using fastway shipping module : in fastway shipping module : fastway.php (Model/carrier) i guess it's taking attributes values as

```
$packageWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
$packageheight = $request->getPackageHeight();
$packagewidth = $request->getPackageWidth();
$packagedepth = $request->getPackageDepth();
```

But as i changed this to `$request->getPackageDimension_weight()` and others like so. It's not calculating shipping value while checking out.

Comment: is PackageWeight  product attribute?Which extension you have using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change in any way the system attributes (except for attribute scope), and weight is one of the system attributes. [See this to understand why](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14839/146).

In your specific case, `weight` is used as it is for calculating shipping charges. All the core shipping modules (that depend on weight) use it.
`$request->getPackageWeight();` is not something that is magically determined based on the attribute code. The package weight is actually calculated and set to the request object.  See the method `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRatesByAddress`. Specially this section: `$request->setPackageWeight($address->getWeight());`. This means that the value of `$request->getPackageWeight()` is the value of `$address->getWeight()`.  Digging deeper and deeper you will see that the weight for a shipping address is determined by the weight of the items for that address and the weight of each item comes from the `weight` attribute of the product associated to the item

This last one (that I think is the origin of everything) comes from `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setProduct()` from the line `->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())`.

You can try changing the line above to

```
->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getDimentionWeight())
```

in order to use your attribute value, but I'm not sure this will work. I don't know the full implications.

My suggestion is to leave the attribute code `weight` as it is. It should not bother your since the attribute codes are only used internally and have no meaning for the user. You can just change the label if you need.

Comment: Good Explaing @marius.. I am to confuse about this thing.Thanks for your answer