# get attributes needed in shipping module

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using a fastway shipping module : It needs three-four attributes to calculate shipping cost, like `height`,`width`,`length`

Inside the module i can see these values being pulled

```
        $packageWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $packageheight = $request->getPackageHeight();
        $packagewidth = $request->getPackageWidth(); 
        $packagelength = $request->getPackageLength();
        $packagedepth = $request->getPackageDepth();
```

Among the attributes `Weight` is the **system attribute** so, i'm able to get that, but those other attributes values are null/zero. I created `length`,`height` and `width` attributes.

So, how can i get those attributes values as i have set some numeric values on those attributes on product.

What i tried is : *Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRatesByAddress* i added below block of code right below`$request->setPackageWeight($address->getWeight());`

```
    $request->setPackageHeight($address->getHeight());
    $request->setPackageLength($address->getLength());
    $request->setPackageWidth($address->getWidth());
    $request->setPackageDepth($address->getDepth());
```

And finally here *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setProduct()* i added this block of code right below `->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())`

```
            ->setHeight($this->getProduct()->getHeight())
            ->setLength($this->getProduct()->getLength())
            ->setWidth($this->getProduct()->getWidth())
            ->setDepth($this->getProduct()->getDepth())
```

Reference to this : [Question's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55138/changed-default-attribute-code-to-other-and-issues-in-shipping-module), still not being able to obtain those custom attributes value in the module(shipping module). What i am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Since there may be multiple items in your cart, there is no easily way to get these values and you would need to sum them similar to 'weight' of all product

The easiest way to accomplish this would be loading the individual product in your shipping module

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
     foreach($request->getAllItems() as $item){
         $_product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
         $itemHeight = $_product->getHeight();
```

Comment: But it doesn't work for single item added for multiple times. as i'm calculating for individual item within the `foreach loop`

Comment: You need to factoring the qty in cart

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem to solve. Some packages were very light but too big to ship with the cheapest rate, so we needed to use the dimensions in our shipping module.

My solution was:

```php
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request) {
      ...
      $package_dimensions = $this->_getPackageDimension($request);
      ...
    }
```

```php
    private function _getPackageDimension(RateRequest $request) {
        $products = [];
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $product = $product->load($product->getId());
            $products[] = $product;
        }
        # if there are multiple products in cart the handling is to complex, so skip!
        if (!(count($products) == 1)) {
            return null;
        }

        $dimensions = [
            $products[0]->getData('custom_packing_height'),
            $products[0]->getData('custom_packing_length'),
            $products[0]->getData('custom_packing_width'),
        ];

        if (!(isset($dimensions[0]) && isset($dimensions[1]) && isset($dimensions[2]))) {
            return null;
        }

        sort($dimensions);
        return $dimensions;
    }
```